# Display a substring in c++ program

Tags: c++, string

Here is the question: Write a program that allows as input an integer that represents a month number (1 – 12) and the program should display the abbreviation for the corresponding month. 
Example: If the input is 3, then the output should be Mar, for March. 
Hint: Store all the month abbreviations in a big string
months = “JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec”

here are my codes so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    string months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";

    cout << "Enter an integer between (1-12): " << endl;
    cin>>x;

    cout<<"\n"<<months.substr(x,3);
    return 0;
}
```

problem: cannot figure out how to get the corresponding abbreviations.

Comment: hint: x indicates the start of the substring and for each index this start should move by more than one

Comment: Read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). Then try to mentally execute your program with different values of `x`. You'll spot the problem immediately. Then solve the problem. Profit. Alternatively, use a debugger.

Comment: In your string `string months = “JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec”` the index of `Jan` is `0, 1, 2`; of `Feb` is `3, 4, 5`;... I suggest you to print the char of string as month number by print the index, example, for `x` is the number of month, you can print sub string by `for` loop: `for(int i = 3 * x; i < 3 * (x + 1) - 1; i++) { //print the char months[i]}`

Comment: Startindex in the string is always given by: (monthnumber-1)*3. length of substring is 3. rest is straight forward...

Comment: Anyone who posted the answers and comments with the solution must realize that they just destroyed an opportunity for this kid to learn how to solve another programming problem. It might be the last one that he tries to solve at all. Next time he'll just come to SO for free solutions. I wish them all to have such well-trained colleagues.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    string months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";

    cout << "Enter an integer between (1-12): " << endl;

    cin >> x;

    cout << months.substr((x-1)*3, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

see: http://ideone.com/0x9amY

Notes:
You should perform bounds check, otherwise you might get 'std::out_of_range'

Also, there is no benefit from storing months like this. Use normal container instead:

```
string months[] = { "Jan", /* and so on */ };
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
const auto n = 3*(x-1);
const auto &abbr = months.substr(n, 3);
std::cout << abbr << std::endl;
```

Which part didn't you get? The fact that C++ is zero-based?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the starting character that matches the month you are dealing with, ie:

```
months.substr( 3*(x-1), 3 );
```

Anyway, this is not the better way to proceed. For you purpose, you should better use an array, this way:

```
const char* month[] = { "Jan", "Feb", ... };
...
cout << month[x-1] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

To "display a substring" you don't literally have to create a `string` temporary with `substr`.  Instead, you can [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) directly to `std::cout`; just pass in a pointer to the first character to print (i.e. `&months[(x - 1) * 3]`), and the number of characters to print:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string months = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";

    cout << "Enter an integer between (1-12): \n";

    int x;
    if (cin >> x && 1 <= x && x <= 12)
        (cout << '\n').write(&months[(x - 1) * 3], 3);
}
```